# System clock is breaking once a week for 17 minutes (1000 seconds)

Tags: 18.04, clock

I have a virtual machine in a data center with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Once a week (the night from Sat to Sun) its system clock runs in a future for 17 mins (1000 secs) which break my applications.
At first I hadn't ntp service installed and I tried to fix it with installing ntp. Later that happened again: ntp fails if the clock is wrong for more than 1000s and can't bring up. I tried to remove -g option from ntp service but it still fails.
Now my setup looks like running ntp service and running in cronjob ntpd -qg once a minute. I hope this would help to have synced clock in general but still the system clock could be wrong for a minute once a week (that breaks my applications).

I tried to look into journal, syslog and other logs but didn't find anything suspicious. I checked weekly cronjobs and there is nothing suspicious there (`man-db  update-notifier-common`) and in fact weekly jobs are running at `47 6  * * 7` which is not matching with breakage time.

I'm looking for a way to track why it gets broken. How can I find all logs about system clock changes?

And which is more important I'm trying to find any clue on who breaks system clock. My only idea now is that the clock are breaking from outside of VM but I can't prove that (support doesn't help much). If it's the case how can I fix the issue?

Comment: have you contacted your host?  you may be right that it has nothing to do within your container, but it could be getting an incorrect time from the server that powers your VM.

Comment: Sure I contacted them several times that but they haven't gave me any adequate answer (basically did nothing to help me).
The issue is still reproducible: it happens now every week on Saturday.